# How to view changes after "Get Latest Version"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I **Get Latest Version** I often want to see what files have changed (and the diff). How do I achieve this with the least amount of IDE navigation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a 'Get Latest Version' preview in TFS? (Like VSS 'Get' command)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657249/is-there-a-get-latest-version-preview-in-tfs-like-vss-get-command)

Comment: You can vote for the feature at [Visual Studio Uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5630060-hook-into-on-get-latest-to-encourage-code-awarenes).

Answer (score 4):

Best thing to do is a folder comparison before you get the latest version. In Source Control Explorer, you can compare the differences between two server folders, two local folders, or a server folder and a local folder. Right click on the target folder and select Compare. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385986.aspx).

Comment: You can do that after the Get as well, in which case you need to know which version you had before (or when your last Get Latest was). You can give that version/date as version to compare your local files with.

Comment: That is proably 20 mouse clicks or more. There has got to be a better way. I just want to see the Changeset Details (keyboard shortcut) and then showing the diff (another keyboard shortcut).

Comment: @ArneEvertsson: I have asked for the same feature as you, but this is the best answer I've got.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a solution to part of your question "what files have changed".

Once you GetLatest, go to View -> output window or (CTRL + W,O). This will show you the list of files that was replaced in the last GetLatest operation. Once you have the list of files you can do file comparison on each file to get the changes.