# How can I tell what will be updated if I use "Get Latest Version"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, tfvc

I have a Visual Studio solution and am using TFS for version control.

When I've made a bunch of changes to my working copy of the solution, the Team Explorer window will show me all the files that I've changed, and allow me to compare my version with either the workspace (original) version, or the latest version in TFS.

However, before I check in my changes, I first want to integrate any changes that have been made (by other people) to the latest TFS version since I got the source from TFS.

I *could* do a Get Latest Version and hope for the best. However, I would generally prefer to know what will be changed, and have the opportunity to look in detail at those changes, *before* overwriting my local files.

Is there a way to either compare my workspace (original) version against the latest version in TFS, or to see what the effects of a "Get" will be before I actually execute it?

To be useful, this would have to be a at a solution level - I would not want to have to go through each individual file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a 'Get Latest Version' preview in TFS? (Like VSS 'Get' command)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657249/is-there-a-get-latest-version-preview-in-tfs-like-vss-get-command)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use <kbd>Compare...</kbd> and select Latest Version. That's best executed from the commandline or the Source Control Explorer.

If you compare "Latest Version" (remote) with "Workspace version" (local), then it'll tell you what has changes on the server since the last get-latest.

If you compare "Latest version (remote) with "Latest version" (local), then it'll tell you what has changed both locally and remotely.

Comment: Great, thanks. It's not quite as slick as the "pending changes" view, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 5):

[The command line is your friend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) you can use the `/preview` switch to see what will happen if you do the get

`tf get $/MyTeamProject/MySourcePath /recursive /preview`